# Cannot seed a <select> listbox with <options>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm feeling my way around using JavaScript to populate a HTML5 page - ultimately to link into a Delphi / Datasnap page.

On my page I have a  tag setup to provide a listbox as below:

```
<select id="FirmList" size="10"></select>
```

I then have a JavaScript script linked to a button that fires on the OnClick

```
function getJobFirms()
{
  var sel = $("#FirmList");
  //var sel = document.getElementByID("FirmList");
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.text = i+1;
    sel.add(opt);
  }
}
```

The above seems to work - in that Chrome reports no errors and loops through 10 times.  However nothing appears in the listbox on the web page, and the length property of sel.option does not increment

I've tried to use other options such as addressing `sel.opt` directly with no luck

Any suggestions?

Comment: Top tip. Learn to use your browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [**.append()**](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

Use

```
sel.append(opt);
```

instead of

```
sel.add(opt);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8p9vy/)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because `sel` is a jQuery object, and you're trying to use the native `select.add()` method, which only works on the native element.

The easy way to fix that would be to do what you seem to have to tried, use `getElementById`, but you've typed it wrong.

```
function getJobFirms() {
  var sel = document.getElementById("FirmList");

  for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.text = i+1;
    sel.add(opt);
  }
}
```

as you're already using jQuery, you could just do something like this

```
function getJobFirms() {
    $("#FirmList").append(function() {
        return $.map(' (. Y .)  '.split(''), function(_,i) {
            return $('<option />', {text : (i+1), value : i});
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: For some reason getElementById was failing at that point - but that's a different question.

Comment: strange way to use `$.map()`

Comment: @DanKelly -  It's failing because you typed it wrong, it's lowercase 'd' at the end.

Comment: @A.Wolff - just an easy way to return 10 options.

Comment: @user3649503 but quite unreadable imho... And what about performance?

Comment: @A.Wolff - is it more readable with boobs? A for loop is obviously faster, but for ten options it doesn't matter.

Comment: @A.Wolff - to be clearer, it creates an array of elements, and passes that array back to append, only running append once, and changing the DOM once, as opposed to ten times in a regular for loop.

Comment: @user3649503 still wrapping ten times a new jQuery object. The best way if that matter would be to use a `for` loop and concatenate a string inside it

Comment: @A.Wolff - creating the element doesn't take any time, changing the DOM does, and every other answer is also creating the element ten times, and even if you used strings, when you pass that string to jQuery or set it as innerHTML, the string would be parsed and ten elements would still be created ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below jQuery script

```
 function getJobFirms()
    {
      var sel = $("#FirmList");
      //var sel = document.getElementByID("FirmList");
      for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        sel.append('<option value="'+i+'">'+(i+1)+'</option>');
      }
    }
```

Here is working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8p9vy/6/)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uU4mk/5/)

Use **append()**;

```
var sel = $("#FirmList");

  for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.text = i+1;
    sel.append(opt);
  }
```

OR  **[DEMO JQUERY](http://jsfiddle.net/uU4mk/6/)**

```
var sel = $("#FirmList");

  for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {

    sel.append($('<option/>',{'text' : i+1},{"value":i}));
   //OR
    sel.append("<option value='"+i+"'>"+(i+1)+"</option>")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery, you can use the following to make it more readable. As noted in the other questions, `add` is not a jQuery method and you need to use any variation of `append`.

```
function getJobFirms()
{
  var sel = $("#FirmList");
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    $('<option/>', {text: i + 1, value: i})
        .appendTo(sel);
  }
}
```